# Specify Cloud Storage bucket of different project for datastore backups?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-datastore, database-backups

I'm trying to setup Datastore backup on our AppEngine project, but I was wondering if it's possible to specify a bucket that's outside of the AppEngine project?

In the [docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/scheduled_backups#Specifying_Backups_in_a_Cron_File), it's not mentioned that it *has* to be in the same project. But it doesn't mention how to specify a bucket outside the project as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can - I have multiple apps backing up to the same bucket. Just specify the gs_bucket_name parameter, and make sure that your app engine service account has write access to the bucket.